# How to open the browser automatically for a User authorization("/Callback")?

Tags: java, spring-boot, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I am trying to upload some videos from my java server to youtube, but I have some confusions with data authorization process. I read a lot of documentation about it
I cannot succeed to show the authorization window automatically to the user, instead of that, I receive a message in the console(of the server) "Please open the following address in your browser:".
I must click on it, so the user can see the authorization window.

```
 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=975725361259-m2pmvjv9uobcpq03tja9i66dtot7lkjv.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload
```

I think I am missing something here..

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,   scopes).setCredentialDataStore(datastore)
            .build();

    // Build the local server and bind it to port 8081
    LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8081).build();
```

How could I solve it, so the user can automatically be redirected to that window in the application(localhost)?

What Am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: How is the user interacting with your application?

Comment: He is sending a request to the server, the server uploads the video to youtube, and the a FCP notification is sent to the user. Everything works, but I must always track the console and click on the link, so the authorization window is shown to the user..

Comment: In which console the server or browser console? You may be able to extract that link and open it in javascript via the `location` object

Comment: In the server console. 
My App works on 8080, and I set the LocalServerReceiver to be on 8081. That could be a problem?

P.S: I tried changing the port, but it is the same.

Comment: I dont believe that that client library is designed web.  Its all of the samples are for console applications that being installed applications.   You would probably have to do something fancy on your own to make java open a web browser for you.

Comment: Thank you for your hint.
I noticed that inside the authorize method this check returns always false:
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) 
On macOS is the "Desktop" is not supported..